# How can I get the title of the current song playing in java using the jacomp3 api

Tags: java, mp3

So I am making an MP3 player in java, everything works except for when a song is over. I don't get the title of the song that is currently playing. Right now I have it to were the user has to keep track, so they need to know when the song is over so they can skip and the title will display. I am using jaco mp3player api but if there is other java api's like it maybe even better please suggest. So far this is the only api I like but I wouldn't mind starting my project over.

Here is how my play and pause work, as you can see I get the song name by going through my array list which stores the songs.

```
// Check if ppTracker is 1 and allow the user to pause
    if (ppTracker == 1) {
        // Change the image icon
        btnPlaynPause.setIcon(unpressPause);
        //songName = musicAccess.getSongName();
        //displaySong.setText(songName);
        displaySong.setText(music.get(mTracker).getSongName());
        player.play();
        System.out.println("Size "+player);

        // Check if ppTracker is 2 and allow the user to resume or play
    } else if (ppTracker == 2) {
        // Change the image icon
        btnPlaynPause.setIcon(unpressPlay);
        player.pause();
        // Reset the tracker back to 0
        ppTracker = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check the song a few times a second and make sure the label has the correct text and if not change it accordingly? This can be done with a few methods but the easiest is likely using threads.